# How to resolve The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently working on Grocery Application but getting an error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Tried searching online but got no solution. Flutter Developers help me resolve the error.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel{
  static const NUMBER = 'number';
  static const ID = 'id';

  late String _number;
  late String _id;

  String get number => _number;
  String get id => _id;

  UserModel.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot){
    _number = documentSnapshot.data()![NUMBER];
    _id = documentSnapshot.data()![ID];
  }
}
```

[image: Error ScreenShot]

UPDATE: ERROR FIXED

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel{
  static const NUMBER = 'number';
  static const ID = 'id';

  String? _number;
  String? _id;

  String? get number => _number;
  String? get id => _id;

  UserModel.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> documentSnapshot){
    _number = documentSnapshot.data()![NUMBER];
    _id = documentSnapshot.data()![ID];
  }
}
```

Comment: `DocumentSnapshot` is generic so you should specify what type of object you expect from it like e.g. `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, String>>`. If you are not doing that, Dart have no idea of what you get from `data()` when compiling.

Comment: did you try it without using `data()` ? Like `documentSnapshot[NUMBER]`

Comment: Thanks, @julemand101 the error is resolved now. Really Appreciate.

Comment: @AryanSethi I tried buy not worked

Comment: @RudranshSinghMahra Great. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important detail for `DocumentSnapshot` is that it is defined with a generic:

> `DocumentSnapshot<T extends Object?>`

https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html

Where `T` is then used by the `data()` method signature:

> `data() → T?`

If we don't specify anything in the generic part, Dart will in this case automatically assume `T` is `Object?`. This is a problem in your case since `Object?` does not have any `[String]` operator.

You therefore need to explicit tell Dart what type you expect `T` to be by doing something like this:

```
UserModel.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> documentSnapshot){
```

Here we tell Dart that `T` in `DocumentSnapshot` should be `Map<String,dynamic>` so when we call `data()`, Dart can assume that you get a `Map<String,dynamic>?` typed object back (notice it will always add `?` at the end because that is how `data()` is defined).